# Combine javascript events

Tags: jquery

I am using a jquery custom scrollbar plugin from :
http://manos.malihu.gr/repository/custom-scrollbar/demo/examples/scrollbar_themes_demo.html

I can use this in my webpage fine if I add the code and dependencies to my header.php page like this :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script src="js/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js"></script>

<link rel='stylesheet' href='css/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.css' type='text/css' media='all' />



<script>
(function($){
    $(window).load(function(){
        $.mCustomScrollbar.defaults.scrollButtons.enable=true; //enable scrolling buttons by default
        $(".results-inner").mCustomScrollbar({theme:"dark-3", mouseWheel: true});
    });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

This issue I am having is that I am using ajax pagination to load more results (posts) where this custom scroll bar appears on each individual posts.

For this reason, it is no longer available after it has already been run on the page load. The good news is, through the method in which I am using this there is supposed JS frontend events where this can be added specifically for a situation like this. So, instead of running this in the header.php, it should actually be added to a defined area in the application that allows these "frontend events" that work like this:

```
jQuery( document ).on( 'js_event_wpv_pagination_completed', function( event, data ) {
    /**
    * data.view_unique_id (string) The View unique ID hash
    * data.effect (string) The View AJAX pagination effect
    * data.speed (integer) The View AJAX pagination speed in miliseconds
    * data.layout (object) The jQuery object for the View layout wrapper
    */

});
```

I have to tried to add it there accurately, with no success. This is what I have:

```
jQuery( document ).on( 'js_event_wpv_pagination_completed', function( event, data ) {
    (function($){
        $(window).load(function(){
            $.mCustomScrollbar.defaults.scrollButtons.enable=true; //enable scrolling buttons by default
            $(".results-inner").mCustomScrollbar({theme:"dark-3", mouseWheel: true});
        });
    })(jQuery);
});
```

Is there anything obvious to what I might be doing wrong here?

Just as a reference I do have a similar scenario in this application that **does work** properly after ajax pagination and parametric search results updated. That code is :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $( document ).on( 'js_event_wpv_pagination_completed', function() {
      my_custom_js_func();
    });
    $( document ).on( 'js_event_wpv_parametric_search_results_updated', function() {
      my_custom_js_func();
    }); 
  my_custom_js_func();
    function my_custom_js_func(){
        $(".card-grid").flip({
            trigger: 'manual'
        });
        $(".flip-btn").click(function () {
            $(this).closest(".card-grid").flip(true);
        });
        $(".unflip-btn").click(function () {
            $(this).closest(".card-grid").flip(false);
        });
    }
});
```

Is there a way to properly combine the custom scroll bar script into the working code I've provided here? These will both always appear together because they are divs that "flip" to show the content on the backside of the div where content has the ability to scroll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your event handler has a bit too much stuff. Try this:

```
jQuery( document ).on( 'js_event_wpv_pagination_completed', function( event, data ) {
    $(".results-inner").mCustomScrollbar({theme:"dark-3", mouseWheel: true});
});
```

Comment: Incredibly helpful. This worked perfectly. Thanks so much!